# where is the error in this perl code

Tags: perl

```
my $secret = int(1+rand(100)); 
LOOP: {

    print "Please enter a guess from 1 to 100: "; 
    chomp(my $guess = <STDIN>);
    my $found_it = 0;
    given( $guess ) { 
        when ( !  /\A\d+\Z/ ) { say "Not a number!" } 
        when ( $_ > $secret ) { say "Too High!" } 
        when ( $_ < $secret ) { say "Too low!" } 
        default { say "Just right!"; $found_it++ } 
    }
    last LOOP if $found_it; 
    redo LOOP;
}
```

This code cannot run. I cannot find what mistakes are! 
[image: Errors in pic.]

Comment: Could you actually tell us what the IDE says?

Comment: What are lines 1-7?

Comment: ide doesn't tell me the specific problem

Comment: then get a new IDE.  but just looking at it, I would suspect clicking on the red x's and yellow yield signs would show more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like whatever you are using isn't recognizing the newer keywords you are using.

If you aren't already, enable them with:

```
use 5.010; # or higher
# or
use feature 'switch';
```

In addition, on newer Perl versions, you will need to say

```
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

since you are implicitly using smartmatch, and the way that works is planned to change in a future Perl version.